# How to join a list member and indicative member to create list of indicative and list member

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose I have classes like:

```
public class LabeledStock {
     public Stock StockInfo { get; set; }
     public IList<Label> Labels { get; set; }
}

public class StockLabel {
     public Stock StockInfo {get; set; }
     public Label Label {get; set; } 
}
```

I am struggling to find the correct way to write a Linq expression that converts a list of `LabeledStock` objects to a list of `StockLabel` objects (i.e. flattening the Labels property but keeping it together with the stock object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var result= labeledStockList.SelectMany(e=>e.Labels.Select(l=>new StockLabel{StockInfo=e.StockInfo,Label=l}));
```

Comment: ah, that's it... I was playing with SelectMany but couldn't get the second part. Thanks for the help!